# I get $ \int fg' \, dx = 2fg + \int fg'\,dx + C $ while performing integration by parts. What did I do wrong?

Tags: integration, paradoxes

I am reaching a paradox by using integration by parts. I must be going wrong but unable to figure where I went wrong. Can you help me understand what I did wrong here?

We have two differentiable functions $ f(x) $ and $ g(x) $. Now we start with $ \int f(x) g'(x) dx $ and proceed like this:

$$
\int fg' \, dx = fg + \int f'g \, dx + C = fg + fg + \int fg'\,dx + C = 2fg + \int fg'\,dx + C.
$$

What went wrong here?

**Update:**

As told in the first comment to this post I have made a very silly error. Here is the fix now:

$$
\int fg' \, dx = fg - \int f'g \, dx + C = fg - fg + \int fg'\,dx + C = \int fg'\,dx + C.
$$

So there is no issue.

Comment: You need a minus sign in the integration by parts formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told in the first comment to this post I have made a very silly error. Here is the fix now:

$$
\int fg' \, dx = fg - \int f'g \, dx + C = fg - fg + \int fg'\,dx + C = \int fg'\,dx + C.
$$